# How to change Query output

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I have the down query that output the down results using union, and I want to reformat the output to the next format.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
 F.FIELD,
   ROUND((ROUND(SUM(F.INJECTION_ VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  INJECTION
   FROM INJECTION F
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY'),
   F.F_CD
   HAVING TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
   UNION
   SELECT TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
   S.FIELD, 
   ROUND((ROUND(SUM(S.PROD_VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  PRODUCTION
   FROM PRODUCTION P
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY'),
   S.FIELD
   HAVING TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
   ORDER BY 1
```

OUTPUT

```
YEAR        FIELD       INJECTION
2013        FARM        122.35
2013        FARM        123.73
2013        DARM         59.99
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
YEAR        FIELD       PRODUCTION      INJECTION
2013        FARM        122.35          123.75
2013        DARM        59.99
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used your code (with some modifications) as t1 and t2 and joined the two tables so that the results come in rows (instead of unioning together):

```
select t1.YEAR, t1.FIELD, t2.PRODUCTION, t1.INJECTION
from (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR, F.FIELD, ROUND((ROUND(SUM(F.INJECTION_ VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  INJECTION
        FROM INJECTION F
        WHERE TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY'),F.F_CD
    ) as t1
    full outer join (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR, S.FIELD, ROUND((ROUND(SUM(S.PROD_VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  PRODUCTION
            FROM PRODUCTION S
            WHERE TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
            GROUP BY TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY'),S.FIELD
        ) as t2 on t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR and t1.FIELD = t2.FIELD
```

Note that for the last value, we'll have "NULL" in the result set. To change null to zero (or anything else) you may use isnull(field, 0) in MS SQL Server or ifnull(field, 0) in MySQL.

Comment: What do you mean? t1 and t2 are just names. They can be anything.

Comment: No, they're not.
Actually as I mentioned above, I just used your code and don't know about your schema. Anyway, seems that you (and me as well) had a mistake in choosing alias for your second select ("FROM PRODUCTION P" should be "FROM PRODUCTION S", because you are using only "S" in that "Select"). 
Try this updated code.

Comment: Thanks Alisa, i used the updated code, now i am getting sql not properly ended, wondering if the parenthesis are placed correctly.

Comment: Hi, i did somemodifications, but still did not get what i need,

Comment: What is your schema for Injection and Production? Send me the "create table ..." statements for those two tables. A couple of records is also useful.

Comment: Try updated answer. You had a mistake in your query. You should put simple conditions in "where", not "having". Also you are using Oracle, right? TO_CHAR() function is for Oracle. It doesn't work on MS SQL Server and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT T.Year,T.FIELD,T.INJECTION,S.PRODUCTION
From
(
   SELECT TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
          F.FIELD,
          ROUND((ROUND(SUM(F.INJECTION_ VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  INJECTION
   FROM INJECTION F
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY'),F.F_CD
   HAVING TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
) T Join
(
   SELECT TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
          S.FIELD, 
          ROUND((ROUND(SUM(S.PROD_VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  PRODUCTION
          FROM PRODUCTION P
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY'),S.FIELD
   HAVING TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
) T1 ON T.Year = T1.Year And T.FIELD = S.FIELD
```

Answer (score 0):

There is specific technique to convert columns into rows. You can use that.
I can outline the following principle. You can rewrite a run. 
You can add group by clause to outermost select statement if needed.
Above answers work if tables are only two and have specific data.Following is a general technique.

Example:

```
   SELECT YEAR, FIELD, 
    CASE WHEN TBL = 'PRODUCTION'
         THEN INJECTION
         END PRODUCTION,
    CASE WHEN TBL = 'INJECTION'
         THEN INJECTION
         END INJECTION
    (
   SELECT TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
   F.FIELD,
   ROUND((ROUND(SUM(F.INJECTION_ VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  INJECTION,
   'INJECTION' TBL
   FROM INJECTION F
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY'),
   F.F_CD
   HAVING TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
   UNION
   SELECT TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
   S.FIELD, 
   ROUND((ROUND(SUM(S.PROD_VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  ,
    'PRODUCTION' TBL
   FROM PRODUCTION P.
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY'),
   S.FIELD
   HAVING TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
   ORDER BY 1    
   )
```

I can make suitable modifications in query. Following code gives one more clue.
By writing suitable logic, desired results can be generated.

```
SELECT YEAR, FIELD, 
MAX    (
        CASE WHEN FIELD = 'FARM'
             THEN INJECTION
             END 
) PRODUCTION,
MAX    (        CASE WHEN FIELD <> 'FARM'
             THEN INJECTION
             END 
) INJECTION
        (
       SELECT TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
       F.FIELD,
       ROUND((ROUND(SUM(F.INJECTION_ VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  INJECTION
       FROM INJECTION F
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY'),
       F.F_CD
       HAVING TO_CHAR(F.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
       UNION
       SELECT TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') YEAR,
       S.FIELD, 
       ROUND((ROUND(SUM(S.PROD_VOLUME) / 120, 0) / 1000), 2)  
       FROM PRODUCTION P.
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY'),
       S.FIELD
       HAVING TO_CHAR(S.DATE, 'YYYY') = '2013'
       ORDER BY 1    
       )
GROUP BY YEAR, FIELD
```